# Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM: nano cannot edit empty file

Tags: nano

I have a empty file in home directory, when I run `nano temp4` it gives me error `Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM` and does not open the file

```
@archlinux ➜  ~  ᐅ  nano temp4
    Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
@archlinux ➜  ~  ᐅ  l temp4 
    -rw-r--r-- 1 edward edward 0 May 17 16:04 temp4
@archlinux ➜  ~  ᐅ  file temp4 
    temp4: empty
```

what could be the reason? This has been happening too often lately with many other files.

**However**, I can solve the problem by running `echo > temp4` and then opening it with nano

(I am running Arch Linux. nano 2.5.3)

Comment: Use `strace` and `auditd` to better debug what system calls `nano` is making and where the signal is coming from.

Comment: I have encountered this problem also. Solved it after running `sudo su` before (Debian 9 stretch) .