# Can't create new file with nano, Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

Tags: nano, sighup, sigterm

I found only this question of this subject:  [Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM: nano cannot edit empty file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283620/received-sighup-or-sigterm-nano-cannot-edit-empty-file)

I'm configuring my web server. There wasn't any problems earlier and I would like to know exactly what is causing this error? I've installed samba and php. I tried strace and auditd as adviced in earlier comment but this didn't open up this problem for me.

```
@unity:/var/www/html $ sudo nano info.php
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
@unity:/var/www/html $ sudo rm index.html
@unity:/var/www/html $ sudo nano info.php
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

Comment: Thanks, actually the problem was solved after rebooting. Think that fixed the connection problems on the terminal.